# Ruby on Rails Action Cable: Extending ApplicationCable Connection class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I was wondering if it was possible to extend the action cable connect class so that I can create other 'base controllers' that inherit from the main connection class.

I basically want to do different authentication methods for different streams, and all I am trying to do is essentially do what you do for the application controller where you can have other base controllers that inherit from the application controller.

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not.... What have you tried so far? What problems, if any, are you seeing? I *presume* this can simply by done via standard inheritance, e.g. `class AuthenticatedChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel` and `class NotificationsChannel < AuthenticatedChannel`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to specify different Connection classes for different channels.  I solved this by setting an instance variable and `attr_reader` in the Connection class specifying if the user logged in or not (I have authenticated and unauthenticated channels).  Then from the Channel I would verify the login with `connection.did_login` and raise an exception.  Not the prettiest but it seems to work.